# Using std::string.find() leads me to std::out_of_range

Tags: c++, string, indexoutofrangeexception

I tried to write a code about searching student ID from text file...
I used std::string.find() function but I got an exception "std::out_of_range"

(Actually I'm not good at English.  I'm so sorry..)

The code is below.

```
void search_ID(std::ifstream& f1, int sort_num)
{
    std::string ID;

    std::cout << "Student ID keyword?: " << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, ID);

    if (ID.length() > 10)
    {
        std::cout << "You should type under 10 words" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    std::string line;
    int pos;
    int size = 0;

    while (f1) {
        getline(f1, line);
        **if ((pos = line.substr(20, 10).find(ID)) != std::string::npos) {**
            size++;
        }
    }
// ...
// ...
}
```

The error is on bold typing. Why is it happened..??

Comment: Because some of the lines you read were less than 21 characters in length, and the shown code assumes that all lines are at least 21 characters long?

Comment: You cannot **bold** text in code formatting markdown using `**`. Use code comments instead. Otherwise the `**` might be confused with something you have in your code, and invalidates correct syntax.

Comment: i think a last line in a text file is "\n"... is it problem on this?? Thanks to comment this question. :)

Comment: @Seo Break up your code in single statements. Check if results for each statement are as expected before you proceed calling the next statemen. Robustness is highly significant for good code.

Comment: Thank you. i didn't know that bold text cannot be written in code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how code is compiled with formatting and got the error outofindex ? strange ..